# Parallax Collapse Toolbar wrong scroll and layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have the following layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="br.com.myproject.view.fragment.ProductActivityFragment"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            tools:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            tools:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            tools:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivImgProduct"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                tools:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                tools:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                tools:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                tools:layout_collapseMode="pin">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvProductActions"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

The RecyclerView is getting on the Toolbar are staying with an appearance "overlapped". The scroll both RecyclerView as the CollapsingToolbarLayout not working.
I'm trying to leave my layout with the behavior as this [example link](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout#creating-parallax-animations), but using RecyclerView.

Comment: Try setting a height for the AppBarLayout, something like 170dp.

Comment: I changed the size but this only increases the size of AppBarLayout. My recyclerview is below AppBarLayout and their children. And are not answering the scroll are "frozen".

Comment: Apparently this command not working tools:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts I used a library called [Android-ObservableScrollView](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView) and it worked. It is simpler to use, provides several examples and a single component already has the desired effect. Scroll content has to be greater than the empty screen space for the scroll to take effect because it does not have the bounce effect of iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" to your recyclerview